# Is the dot product of a tensor and a vector commutaive?

Tags: vector, tensor, dot-product

A tensor, **A**, in index notation may be written as A_i,j and a vector **n** in index notation may be written as n_i, where i and j are the indices. My question is **A.n** the same as **n.A**? As  per index notation,
**A.n** = A_i,j * n_j and **n.A** = n_i * A_i,j, which are clearly unequal. However, I am not able to reconcile with the face that it is a dot product and why a dot product is not commutative. Also,if they are unequal, how does one decide which to use :**A.n** or **n.A**?